# xlim(), scale_x_continuous(), don't change axis limits on plot_summs() when plotting density

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I can't get the `plot_summs()` function from the jtools package to centre on zero by manipulating the x limits. It works fine without the density plots as such:

```
test<-lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
plot_summs(test)+xlim(-5,5)
```

But once I add in `plot.distributions=T` to `plot_summs()`, it appears to just ignore it (or `scale_x_continuous()`). Any help appreciated.

```
test<-lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
plot_summs(test)+xlim(-5,5)
```

Also note that using coord_cartisian() achieves this outcome, but not without adding a large space to the plot which I don't know how to remove:

```
plot_summs(test, plot.distributions = T)+coord_cartesian(x = c(-5, 5))
```

I'm stuck! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that plot_summs from jtools? Please specify in question.